# Eloquent eager loading relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Hello wonderful people of StackOverflow, I hope you all have a good day ( ˘⌣˘)♡(˘⌣˘ )

I'm new to Laravel and currently learning about eloquent relationships (hasMany)

> I'm sorry this post was too long to read, but I wanted to clarify every step I did until I ran into problems, and also **sorry if my english is bad** (⁄ ⁄•⁄ω⁄•⁄ ⁄)

So here we go

In my User model

```
public function posts() {
    // A user can have many posts
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

In my Post model

```
public function owner()
{
    // A post belongs to a user
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

In my Post Table, I have 3 simple records

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| id |   user_id |   body          |    ...    |   ...     |
|  1 |   1       |   My first post |    ...    |   ...     |
|  2 |   1       |   Second post   |    ...    |   ...     |
|  3 |   1       |   Another post  |    ...    |   ...     |
```

And then let's say, we want to see the user with id = 1 with all posts they created, so I use the code below:

```
// AccountController
public function profile($id)
{
    $user = App\User::with('posts')->findOrFail($id);
    return $user;
}

// Will return data:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Prof. Angela Runte Jr.",
    "email": "mborer@example.org",
    ...
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "body": "My first post",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "body": "Second post",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "body": "Another post",
            ...
        }
}
```

And in Blade view, I can simply get data like below:

```
// in profile.blade.php

$user->name
$user->...

@foreach($user->posts as $post)
// Show each post data
@endforeach
```

It works perfectly the way I want, Thanks to Taylor Otwell for creating an amazing framework (´• ω •`) ♡

> And then I had an idea in my mind, let's make a feature where **a user can post to other users**, why not? Let's do it! (✧ω✧)

So in my Post migration, I change the table schema:

From:

```
// Before
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unsignBigInteger('user_id');

$table->text('body');
$table->timestamps();
```

To:

```
// After
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

// New column: nullable()
$table->foreign('for_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('for_id')->nullable();

$table->text('body');
$table->timestamps();
```

As you can see, I put nullable() in column 'for_id'

> In words, if for_id is empty then this post belongs only to the user who made the post

> Otherwise the post belongs to the user who made the post, as well as the intended user (for_id).

Then after that, I run

```
// I only use UserSeeder (wanna keep it simple tho)
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

And now we have 2 users with id = 1 and 2 (Yay!)

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id |   name                    |   email                     |    ...     |    ...     |
|  1 |   Camden Kulas            |   lemke.fabian@example.net  |    ...     |    ...     |
|  2 |   Mrs. Roberta Stroman    |   ybartoletti@example.com   |    ...     |    ...     |
```

Let's use tinker for creating dummy data

```
php artisan tinker
>> $user = App\User::first();
=> App\User {#3910
       id: 1,
       name: "Camden Kulas",
       email: "lemke.fabian@example.net",
       ...
   }
>> $user->posts()->create(['body' => 'New first post']);
=> App\Post {#4120
       body: "New first post",
       user_id: 1,
       updated_at: "2020-08-30 03:42:43",
       created_at: "2020-08-30 03:42:43",
       id: 1,
   }

// we create one for Mrs. Roberta Stroman (user with id #2)
>> $user->posts()->create(['for_id' => 2, 'body' => 'Hello there']);
=> App\Post {#3912
       for_id: 2,
       body: "Hello there",
       user_id: 1,
       updated_at: "2020-08-30 03:44:18",
       created_at: "2020-08-30 03:44:18",
       id: 2,
   }
```

So now we have 2 record in our posts table

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id |   user_id |   for_id        |   body              |   ...     |
|  1 |   1       |   NULL          |   New first post    |   ...     |
|  2 |   1       |   2             |   Hello there       |   ...     |
```

> We're still in user id #1

```
>> $user->posts

=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4120
       all: [
           App\Post {#4125
               id: 1,
               user_id: 1,
               for_id: null,
               body: "New first post",
               ...
           },
           App\Post {#4128
               id: 2,
               user_id: 1,
               for_id: 2,
               body: "Hello there",
               ...
           },
       ],
   }
```

(￣ω￣) Ok 'till here, all works fine, let's try with user id #2

> In my mind, I want to get user id #2, and with all posts made by id # 2, **and all posts from others for id # 2**

```
>> $user = App\User::find(2);
=> App\User {#4121
       id: 2
       name: "Mrs. Roberta Stroman",
       email: "ybartoletti@example.com",
       ...
   }
>> $user->posts
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4067
       all: [],
   }
```

> Σ(°ロ°) The posts is empty, so why the hell it's empty?

> ఠ ͟ಠ Then I try to use with()

```
>> $user = App\User::with('posts')->find(2);
=> App\User {#4120
       id: 2,
       name: "Mrs. Roberta Stroman",
       email: "ybartoletti@example.com",
       ...
       posts: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4123
           all: [],
       },
   }
```

(ꐦ°᷄д°᷅) What?? Why The posts still empty? щ(ºДºщ)

So, after searching and reading for days, still I couldn't figured it out how to solve this (｡╯︵╰｡)

And then I tried to change in my User model: the posts() function

From:

```
public function posts()
{
    // A post belongs to a user
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

To:

```
public function posts()
{
    // In my logic like:
    // Hey I want to fetch all posts that made by this user, **or where all posts that created by others for this user**
    // Make sense in human language right?
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user_id')->orWhere('posts.for_id', $this->id);
}
```

I exited the tinker, then re-enter the tinker again

```
>> $user = App\User::first();
// return user id #1

>> $user->posts
// works fine, return all posts
```

> (ಠ益ಠ) Now I am facing other problem

```
>> $user = App\User::with('posts')->first(); // notice that I'm using with()

// tinker return the desired user, and also return ONLY one post

>> App\User {#4123
       id: 1,
       name: "Camden Kulas",
       email: "lemke.fabian@example.net",
       ....
       posts: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4130
           all: [
               App\Post {#4128
                   id: 1,
                   user_id: 1,
                   for_id: null,
                   body: "New first post",
                   created_at: "2020-08-30 03:42:43",
                   updated_at: "2020-08-30 03:42:43",
               },

               // where is the second post?
           ],
       },
   }
```

Then I try to change tinker session with user id #2

```
>> $user = App\User::find(2);
// return user id #2

>> $user = App\User::with('posts')->find(2);
// return user id #2, but no post (only array all)
```

So without writing further, the questions I want to ask

[#1] Why user #1 only fetch one post, meanwhile he created 2 posts?

> One post without for_id (NULL), and second post with for_id

[#2] How to **make user id #2 to fetch all their posts, and also posts that created for them?**

> Because IMHO posts() function in User model, perfectly make sense for me, but it doesn't work

If there's any unclear explanation, it will edit in time

Thanks in advance

> **Update**

I figured it out that I can simply get all posts by user X and all posts for user X with this way:

```
$user = App\User::find(X);
$posts = $user->posts()->orWhere('for_id', X)->get();
return [
    'user' => $user,
    'posts => $posts
];
```

So now the question comes to my mind:

> How to use with() for $posts?

```
// Like this
$user = App\User::with('allposts')->find(X);
// Return user X and all posts made by X and posted to user X

// So I can simply get data in view like this:

@foreach ($user->allposts as $post)
// Loop all posts by user X and for user X
@endforeach
```

Comment: Instead of typing dummy data in tinker you can use laravel [seed](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding) it will be helpful, answering your question if you created `for_id` foreign field you should create another relation in model so you can get by that field, each new relation = new declaration of it inside model

Comment: @arman Hello, I thank you for your time reading this silly question of mine, so I cannot only use posts() function to fetch all post that made by selected user and also all posts that inteded for selected user?

Comment: You can check [pivot](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) that might help